# What is the .dockerfile extension?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code (1.22.2) offers a file extension named `.dockerfile` in the the save dialog. What is a file with this extension? A Dockerfile is in all documentation and examples, that I've seen so far, only called `Dockerfile`.

[image]

If I enter `Dockerfile` as a file name, a file named `Dockerfile.dockerfile` is created.

Comment: Have you tried it to see if the file actually gets a `.dockerfile` extension? Perhaps it's just an UI thing (e.g. the part inside the parentheses couldn't be left empty).?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. If I enter `Dockerfile` as a file name, a file named `Dockerfile.dockerfile` is created. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Windows operates on files with extensions so my guess is they introduced such extension by themselves. Docker implies the `Dockerfile` name, but you can name the file as you want, as long as you provide it's name to the related docker command.

Answer (score 18):

It appears that "*.dockerfile" is simply an alternative to the conventional "Dockerfile" name. This is perhaps useful if you want to keep a collection of dockerfiles in the same directory. Note the `-f/--file` option in `docker help build`:

> -f, --file string             Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')

In other words, you are not required to use the name "Dockerfile", and the VSCode extension will correctly syntax-highlight any file ending in ".dockerfile".

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you have multiple dockerfiles in a single directory, you can give those abitrary names with the `.dockerfile` extension, and then build those by running `docker build . -f "filename.dockerfile"`

Answer (score 11):

**Dockerfile**

A `Dockerfile` is a text document that contains all the commands a user could call on the command line to assemble an `image`. Using `docker build` users can create an automated build that executes several command-line instructions in succession. `Docker images` are the basis of containers. An `Image` is an ordered collection of root filesystem changes and the corresponding execution parameters for use within a container runtime. An image typically contains a union of layered filesystems stacked on top of each other. **An image does not have state and it never changes**.[More on](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage)

**Dockerfile extension**

A `Dockerfile` has no extension . if your using docker on docker on windows use `notepad ++` to create a dockerfile while saving select “All type “ and save the file name as “Dockerfile”.

**Mongodb/Dockerfile**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. As you can see, there _is_ a `.dockerfile` extension, even if docker files usually don't have one.

Comment: This answer reads like a mix of some statements not answering the question and some statements advertising docker.

Comment: Docker can deal with files simply named `Dockerfile`, not requiring an extension. However, let's say you have a directory with 2 or more different dockerfiles, you can give those an arbitrary name with the `.dockerfile` extension, and then build those by running `docker build . -f "filename.dockerfile"`. Your answer is therefore incomplete at best.

Answer (score 6):

Using the .dockerfile extension tells VSCode that the file is a DockerFile for code highlighting and linting

Comment: VSCode does code highlighting and linting for files called `Dockerfile` as well.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to save the file in VS Code as a Dockerfile.  But, you need to remove the .dockerfile extension that VS Code puts on it before running the $docker-compose up command:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Even though VSCode can deal with extensionless files just fine, some major parts of the Windows operating system can't. Try double clicking a `Dockerfile` (without extension) in the Windows Explorer. You will always be asked which program you want to open it in because Windows can't map extensionless files to a default program.

My guess is that because of this problem, Microsoft would like for all files to have an extension and uses VSCode to nudge people towards using a file extension for Dockerfiles, ignoring the fact that this contradicts the de facto standard.

Comment: Double click is for running executable programs. What do you expect to happen when you double click on it? Build the image? Run the image? Or just open a text editor?

Comment: @OneCricketeer You can easily configure Windows to open any file (with a file extension) with any program on a double click. You cannot do that with a file which has no file extension. I consider your first sentence to be incorrect/incomplete. As to your question: I expect the default program for a Dockerfile to be a text editor.

Answer (score -2):

Dockerfile doesn't have any extensions.
As you can see from hte documentation, https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/, it doesn't have any extensions.

[image: Dockerfile]